# Why is Outlook substracting 1px from img?

Tags: html, outlook

I am having a outlook html email nightmare here.. Basically there is one table and one image on the top and content on the bottom.:

[image]

The image is always substracting 1px so it is never 100% with the table. Anyone knows a solution?

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style=
"margin-left:2px;padding:0px; width:846px; background-color:#000">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="font-size: 0px;"><img border="0" src=
            "img/header1.jpg" style=
            "display:block;align:bottom;border:none;padding:0; width:846px;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Blah.. Content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: because it's rubbish!

Comment: outlook is rubbish... it is more rubbish than designing for IE

Comment: have you tried adding an attribute of `width="846"` to the `img` tag, some versions go proper old school and ignore the style tags, you may also need to add style tags at the top of your template - I have found that I usually have to do style tags, inline styling and old school attributes when coding for emails but the best bet for ultra designed emails is usually just to send an image with a link a html version of the page

Comment: I'd suspect it has something to do with the table borders rendering problem. Use Google:`site:stackoverflow.com ie table border collapse` and can you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: The problem looks different on every outlook version... BUT if I send the email it will be displayed correctly. So the problem exists only in the editor. I guess outlook uses two rendering engines, word and internet exploder

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is from outlook's issue with `border-collapse`. Try this:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse; padding:0; margin:0px;">
    <tr valign="top">
        <td align="left" valign="top">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/640/300" width="640" height="300" alt="" style="display:block;" border="0" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the *img* tag for images.

Outlook uses Word for rendering HTML markup. You can read more about that in the following series of articles:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: OP **did use img**. So how is this answer supposed to solve the problem?